# function statement requires a name error in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function but it gives me function statement require name onStop function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery( function($) {
    $('#Hnav, #Nnav').NestedSortable(
            {
                accept: 'sort',
                noNestingClass: "no-children",
                helperclass: 'helper',
                autoScroll: true,
                onChange: function(serialized) {
                onStop : function(){
                    $('#output').html($(this).id);
                },
                    nestingPxSpace : '0'
            }
    );
});
</script>
```

Comment: You didn't close the onChange function correctly so there is a parentheses mismatch

Answer (score 4):

In this context, `this` refers to the DOM element on which the `onStop` event happens. A DOM element is not a jQuery object.

jQuery `$(this)` object doesn't have `id` property, while the DOM elements do. So, use either:

```
$('#output').html(this.id);
```

or:

```
$('#output').html($(this).attr("id"));
```

And don't forget to close the bracket in `onChange` handler function.

Comment: The answer would be better if you explained the *why*

Comment: @FlorianMargaine Can't do it better :)

Comment: May I? :-p I'd just add what `this` is, so the *why* one works while another doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bracket missing and you use wrong syntax getting id try this,

```
$('#output').html($(this).id);
```

should be

```
$('#output').html(this.id);
```

or

```
$('#output').html($(this).attr(id));

  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#Hnav, #Nnav').NestedSortable({
        accept: 'sort',
        noNestingClass: "no-children",
        helperclass: 'helper',
        autoScroll: true,
        onChange: function(serialized) {
            alert("changed");// Changed to fix
        },               
        onStop: function() {
             $('#output').html(this.id);
        },
        nestingPxSpace: '0'       
    });
});​
```

Comment: no it's not ... bracket is missing right before the onStop parameter

Comment: Try again ... onStop won't be inside onChange

Comment: God, you don't even understand what this does does, do you?

Comment: Please ignore the -2 answer and concentrate on the +2 one and the comments

Comment: I have changed the answer check it again @Zoha Ali Khan and all.

Comment: @Adil still wrong. The bracket matter if ok, but your code still won't work.

Comment: just move the final closing brackets into the code level and change `$(this).id` to `this.id`

Comment: I changed $(this).id but could not understand changing closing bracket I think it is at right place

Comment: Thanks @devnull69, so nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

Collectively there are two problems in the code,

1. The inner function was not closed properly.
2. Used id property of element that is not supported by the jQuery selector.

The modified code is,

```
jQuery( function($) {
    $('#Hnav, #Nnav').NestedSortable(
            {
                accept: 'sort',
                noNestingClass: "no-children",
                helperclass: 'helper',
                autoScroll: true,
                onChange: function(serialized) {
                    //A empty function
                },
                onStop : function(){
                    $('#output').html($(this).attr("id"));
                },
                nestingPxSpace : '0'
            }
    );
});
```

Comment: there is a problem in JS still when I load the page it says jQuery("#" + s).get(0) is undefined

Comment: As far as this code is considered there is no problem now this problem is with the NestedSortable javasciprt file you are using in your code. Also check the HTML #Hnav, #Nnav this could be a problems also.

Comment: Thanks for your help i fixed it. I have an issue with toggeling can you please help me?

Comment: Why not share your problem. If you are not able to toggle things. I need HTML code and JavaScript code also

Comment: wait let me create a question

Comment: can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11245640/toggle-the-next-ul-in-li