# Toggle the next ul in li

Tags: jquery

I want to toggle the ul when I click on group1 or group2

HTML

```
<li class="sort">
  <span></span>
  <a class='expand'>Group1</a>
  <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Delete</a>
  <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Edit</a>
  <ul id="0" style='display:none'>
    <li style='border:none' id="1" class='sort'>
        <span></span>
        <a href='#'>Patent 1</a>
        <em style='padding-left: 60px;'>The description of patent 1</em>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Delete</a>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li style='border:none' id="2" class='sort'>
        <span></span>
        <a href='#'>Patent 2</a>
        <em style='padding-left: 60px;'>The description of patent 2</em>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Delete</a>
        <a style='padding-right:10px; float:right' href='#'>Edit</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

I tried

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks

Comment: Seeing there are plenty of answers, I won't post one :D But yet another alternative: siblings:  $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow');

Comment: he Zoha, Please refer @James Allardice's answer

Comment: At bottom note, SO is a good community & you can find solutions to all technical problems as quick as possible. Because not I we form the strength of SO (StackOverflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and then reduce the matched set to the first element with [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('ul').eq(0).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

The `next` method will return the *immediately following* sibling, if it matches the selector. In your case, that's the "Delete" link, which does not match.

If there is always only going to be one `ul` element as a child of the `li`, you can just use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$('.expand').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('ul').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also just target the ul via it's ID:

```
$('a.expand').on('click',function(e){
    $('ul#0').slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

If you're adapting this to work with multiple groups have you considered giving the a an attribute that matches it's ul's selector?

```
$('a.expand').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    $('ul#'+id).slideToggle('slow');
 });
```

That way your code still works if the arrangement of the DOM changes.

Comment: I think the point is there are going to be multiple "groups". This will only work for this specific one. And note that numbers are valid `id` values in HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your code with here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.expand').click(function() {
        $(this.parentNode).children('ul').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

There is no `<UL>` next to the `<A>`!

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wGpK/)**